# Ionic React - How to prevent rerendering routes created by Ionic Tabbar

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, router, tabbar

I am using Ionic Framework with React to create an app with four main tabs. One of the tabs is a map component. My problem is that when I switch tabs, React rerenders them every time. For example, lets say user found a location on map and wanted to see another tab, then switched back to the map. User must be able to continue where he left it on map. Is there any way to achieve that?

Code:

```js
<IonTabs>
  <IonRouterOutlet>
    <Route exact path="/map">
      <Map />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/second">
      <Second />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/Third">
      <Third />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/fourth">
      <Fourth />
    </Route>
  </IonRouterOutlet>

  <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
    <IonTabButton tab="map" href="/map">
      <IonLabel>Map</IonLabel>
    </IonTabButton>
    <IonTabButton tab="second" href="/second">
      <IonLabel>Second</IonLabel>
    </IonTabButton>
    <IonTabButton tab="third" href="/third">
      <IonLabel>Third</IonLabel>
    </IonTabButton>
    <IonTabButton tab="fourth" href="/fourth">
      <IonLabel>Fourth</IonLabel>
    </IonTabButton>
  </IonTabBar>
</IonTabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to save the state of the map in the component so that when it is rerendered, the map shows the appropriate information.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to do that if I can't figure it out. Isn't there a way to keep tabs in the memory instead of removing them from Virtual DOM and rerender every time?